# Django CSRF Causes Server To Bug Out After Bad URL Requests

Tags: python, django, csrf, middleware

When I send an Ajax request that includes a CSRF token to an invalid URL and then follow it up with any request afterwards, body data from the first Ajax request is prepended to the next request, making the request invalid. If that second request is coming from a new browser window, the “invalid CSRF” page is returned even though it is the first time opening the home page of my site from a fresh window.

The following requests are then processed correctly assuming they’re valid.

The problem occurs any time a request with an csrf token header is sent to an invalid URL.

Not sure how to solve this other than removing CSRF altogether which is not preferable.

Django 2.1.4
Python 3.7

I started a project and reproduced the bug with minimal code. It is definitely a bug in the CSRF code I think.. Here is the entire project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

Test worked


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    var token = "{{csrf_token}}";
    var conf = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "bad",
        data: {title: "Title Here"},
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": token
        }
    }

    function badSubmit() {
        $.ajax(conf);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After running that page, the next get request to the server, no matter where it's coming from, will break. The server log will output a line that makes no sense:

```
[03/Aug/2019 15:02:56] "title=Title+HereGET / HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

And my view just to convince you that it isn't my code causing problems:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_view(request):
    return render(request, "test.html", {})
```

If you start up the page, run badSubmit() in the dev console, the NEXT request sent to the server will be processed incorrectly by the Django server, doesn't matter what that next request is. Correct my if I'm wrong, but this is definitive proof that CSRF middleware is breaking or the Django server is breaking when CSRF token is sent. The bug doesn't occur when the CSRF token header isn't included. Default django settings for everything.

Comment: How are you running your server?

Comment: add the `csrf token` as a data not headers and set the key to `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. See if it works or not.

Comment: I don't have any insight into this problem, but if you're right it would certainly be a serious bug, so if you have a reproducible project I would definitely recommend filing a [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/).